# Sorting evens and odds between the range of two integers using while loops?

Tags: java, integer, sum

NOTE: (I do not need anyone to write the whole program for me, I only need the algorithm!)

I need to create a program that prompts the user to enter two integers. The program then needs to list all the even numbers in between the two inputed integers and output the sum. And then the same for the odd numbers. (using While loops)

I will then need to rewrite the code to use a do-while loop, and then rewrite it AGAIN using a for loop.

Here is an example of what the result should look like:

```
Enter an integer: 3
Enter another integer larger than the first: 10

Even Numbers: 4, 6, 8, 10
Sum of even numbers = 28

Odd Numbers: 3, 5, 7, 9
Sum of odd numbers = 24}
```

I tried starting off with the even numbers with something like this, but it just gets stuck at the first number, even if the first number is even.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EvenOddSum_While {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
    int num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("And another: ");
    int num2 = keyboard.nextInt();


    while (num1 < num2){
        while (num1 %2 == 0){
            System.out.print(num1 + ", ");
            num1++;
            }                   
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: You need a lot. But what have you tried so far? This is not a do-my-homework-for-me-page.

Comment: I already know how to use all these loops. I pretty much only need help with the algorithms. For some reason I can't wrap my tiny little brain around it.

Answer (score 0):

The inner while has no end criteria, you need if there instead. Also, your num1++ Statement must be in the outer while loop, not the inner one.

Also, there is no real algorithm here, you're struggling with the language itself ;)

General advice: either run through your code with a step-by-step debugger, virtually every IDE has one OR place excessive log /System.out.println statements in your code to understand what it's doing

Answer (score 0):

When you said 'in between' did you mean including the two integers? Because you did include them. Okay. So do this.

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int even = 0;
int odd = 0;
int evenx = 0;
int oddx = 0;
int evena = 0;
int odda = 0;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
//Prompts the user to input the first number
x = scan.nextInt();
//Prompts the user to input the second number
y = scan.nextInt();

for(int i = x;i<y;i++,x++;){
if(x%2 = 0){
even = even + x;
evenx++;
}
if(x%2 = 1){
odd = odd + x;
oddx++;
}

}

evena = even/evenx;
odda = odd/oddx;

//print it out. There. The algorithm.
```

God. Do this site have auto-format?

Comment: Awesome! Much appreciated!

Comment: I have to have a reputation of at least 15 to upvote an answer.

Comment: Wow. Stack overflow doesnt even let people who ask questions upvote ansers that they like...just wow.